# Connecting DataView webpart to Listview webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, display-form, web-part-connection

For a customer I have to display related data on a CustomDispForm.aspx page. So I started to add a Listview webpart tot the page showing content from the list with the related data. But when I tried to create a connection between the two webparts I kind of got stuck.

I tried creating the connection with SharePoint Designer, but I'm unable to assing columns to match.

Is there any way to send a property from the DataView to the listview?

Comment: you are trying to pass filter values or parameters?